# How does Djoser account verification system really works under the hood?

Tags: django-rest-framework, django-rest-framework-simplejwt, djoser

So I'm currently in an attempt to make my own account verification system and I'm using some parts of Djoser as a reference. let me try to walk you to my question

Let's say you're to make a new account in Djoser app

1. you put in the information of your soon to be made account including email
2. submit the form to the backend
3. get an email to the whatever email account you put in earlier to verify your account
4. click the link in your email
5. get to the verify account page

now in this page there's a button to submit a UID and a token and both of those information lies in the URL.

My question is:

1. What are those tokens? is it JWT?
2. How do they work?
3. How can I implement that in my own projects without djoser?

Comment: Sorry, I don't understand, what exactly you refer as 'codes': the uid and token?

Comment: yeah token that's what I meant, my bad. I'm editing my question!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The answers to your questions are immersed in the own code of djoser.
You can check `djoser.email` file and in the classes there, they are few methods `get_context_data()`.

```
def get_context_data(self):
    context = super().get_context_data()
    user = context.get("user")
    context["uid"] = utils.encode_uid(user.pk)
    context["token"] = default_token_generator.make_token(user)
    context["url"] = settings.ACTIVATION_URL.format(**context)
    return context
```

So get the context in the class where is instance, and in this context add the 'uid' (this is basically `str(pk)` and coded in base64, check `encode_uid()`), the 'token' (just a random string created with a Django function from your Secret key; you can change the algorithm of that function and the duration of this token with `PASSWORD_RESET_TIMEOUT` setting) to use temporary links, and finally the URL according the action which is performed (in this case the email activation).

Other point to consider is in each of this classes has template assigned and you can override it.

Now, in the views, specifically in `UserViewSet` and its actions `perform_create()`, `perform_update()` and `resend_activation()`, if the Djoser setting `SEND_ACTIVATION_EMAIL` is `True`, call to  `ActivationEmail`  to send an email to the user address.

```
 def perform_create(self, serializer):
        user = serializer.save()
        signals.user_registered.send(
            sender=self.__class__, user=user, request=self.request
        )

        context = {"user": user}
        to = [get_user_email(user)]
        if settings.SEND_ACTIVATION_EMAIL:
            settings.EMAIL.activation(self.request, context).send(to)
        ...
```

The email is sent and when a user click the link, whether the token is still valid and uid match (`djoser.UidAndTokenSerializer`), the action `activation()` of the same View is executed. Change the user flag 'is_active' to `True` and it may sent another email to confirm the activation.

If you want code your own version, as you can see, you only have to create a random token, generate some `uid` to identify the user in the way that you prefer. Code a pair of `views` that send emails with templates that permit the activation.